# When to choose Lantids and how to make the most from them

Tags: gaia-project

I love Gaia Project. But there are some races I havn't quite "cracked" yet. So I figured I would try to start a thread here for each race.

I will then provide a response with the do's and don'ts that I've figured out so far.

Some things are always relevant before you choose a race. Such as the amount and layout of the planets. The more planets of the right colour, the better. Even more so, if there are planets nearby, that only needs to be terraformed a single step to become habitable. And hopefully they are not all situated near the border of the map. You also want to start near other players. No need to address these points each and every time.

So: When to choose Lantids, and how to make the most from them?

Summary of the Lantids, for those who do not remember : Lantids has the ability to build mines on planets already colonized by other players. The Lantids won't have to pay anything for terraforming when doing so, but will not be able to upgrade these mines, and these planets will NOT count, when a check is made for number of Gaia planets colonized or the amount of different planet types colonized, as these planets were not originally colonized by the Lantids. When the Planetary Institute is built, the Lantids will get a bonus 2 tech every time they build a mine on a planet already colonized by another player.

Answer (score 2):

Lantids will become more attractive to pick, the more of the following are true:

- It will be easier to find suitable planets to colonize in games with high player count. So they will be more attractive in a four player game, than in games with fewer players.
- During the first or second turn, you will get bonus points for building your Planetary Institute
- The round booster giving points for each mine is in play. Lantids should on average have a high number of mines in play already midgame.

Lantids will become less attractive to pick, the more of the following are true:

- One of the endgame bonuses is for number of colonized Gaia planets.
- One of the endgame bonuses is for number of different planet types colonized.
- It's a two- or three-player game.

During the game, you will probably want to:

- Get your Planetary Institute on the board early, enabling your special ability to get tech every time you build a mine on another players planet.
- Once your Planetary Institute is in play, you should spam mines. This will elevate your income of Iron, and net you a nice boost in tech.
- Save one or two mines, though. And be very careful to only build these on planets that have neighbours. Thus you will be able to upgrade them to Trading Stations at the cheap rate, and get the mine back for colonizing new planets later on.

(My personal best score with Lantids at the time of writing this is a mere 148 points. So take my advices for what they are. I'm sure there's more to consider.)